# Overhead (speed & garbage) of calling functions that do nothing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jit

I am trying to reduce the performance/garbage collection costs of logging statements. I want to have lots of logging statements that I could enable for debugging, but also have a way to turn them off for fast production.

I ran a benchmark on calling the following methods:

```
public static final isLogging = false; 

public static logObjs(Object[] params) {
  if(isLogging)
    System.out.println(params[0]);
}

public static log3Obj(Object a, Object b, Object c) {
  if(isLogging)
     System.out.println(a);
}

public static logInts(int a, int b, int c) {
  if(isLogging)
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

I benchmarked the functions with a driver method

```
long sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
   int a = i; int b = i+1; int c = i+2;
   logFoo(a,b,c);
   sum += a; }
```

logObjs(i, i+1, i+2) takes about 2 seconds for 1e8 iterations and produces lots of garbage.  The sources are, I assume, autoboxing of integers and the Object[] creation for the variable # of parameters.

log3Obj produces a lot (though less) garbage and takes about 1.2 seconds; again, I assume the autoboxing still happens.

logInts is very fast (0.2 sec), just as fast as the loop with no function call.

So, the issue is that even though the function deterministically doesn't do anything, the autoboxing still happens.  In my code, I'd actually prefer to have isLogging not be final, but rather have it be a runtime parameter, but in order to do that, this simpler case (where the compiler can prove that the function doesn't do anything) should run.  Of course, I can replace all my logging statements with

```
if(isLogging)
   logObjs(a, b, c);
```

but that's very inelegant.  I thought this is something that the JIT should take care of.  I've tried a bunch of compiler settings, but maybe there's something I'm missing?  How do I make the code not generate so much garbage while doing nothing?

Comment: "How do I make the code not generate so much garbage while doing nothing?" stop autoboxing

Comment: I would not put any faith in a slapdash "benchmark" like this. Read on: 
http://code.google.com/p/caliper/wiki/JavaMicrobenchmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremly similar to this question: [Will the Java optimizer remove parameter construction for empty method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092004/will-the-java-optimizer-remove-parameter-construction-for-empty-method-calls/3092053#3092053)

As I wrote there: the JIT very well might realize that it will not have to do anything (a bit less in your case as its more involved). But apparantly it does not seem to do so.

What I would propose is a to make multiple log methods, a general one with some vararg parameters and some overloaded ones taking integers and preventing autoboxing in the first place:

```
Log(Object... arguments) { /* do logging */ }
Log(Object a, Object b, Object c}  { /* special case for 3 objects */ }
Log(int a, int b, int c}  { /* special case for 3 ints */ }
```

UPDATE: Better yet, see Péter Török 'do not re-invent the wheel' answer...

Answer (score 4):

You should really prefer an existing logging framework like Log4J instead of reinventing the wheel. Those guys have put in way more effort into optimizing their logging framework than you can ever realistically have. See the "Performance" section near the end of this [Short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Moreover, don't try to optimize prematurely. Chances are, putting serious effort into optimizing logging statements (or for that matter, whichever part of your app) *without actual measurements and proof that this actually improves things* is not going to pay off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In the real program, the code I'm writing is a wrapper around log4j that adds some features.  However, my understanding is that log4j suffers from the same problem.  In particular, the section that you point to, bullet point 1. specifies exactly the cost I'm trying to minimize.  It suggests an unappealing alternative -- littering my non-logging code with if(isLogging) { doLog(); } constructs.  I am hoping to find a cleaner way.  In C++, I'd use templates to auto-generate a whole bunch of logger methods that would avoid boxing ...

Comment: I would hardly call using if (log.isDebugEnabled()) "littering". It's pretty standard, and done for a good reason. You can easily set your IDE up to use a code template so that typing just a few keystrokes will generate the full line of code for you.

Comment: @bsdfish, yes, that's true. You could try improving your API to avoid autoboxing and help the JIT optimizer, as suggested by others. But don't go too far with it - API design should not be directed by performance optimizing concerns. Then, _if_ you have an application where logging is proven to be a bottleneck, you can still add those ugly ifs as a last resort.

Comment: Of course it's littering!  It's a major abstraction violation and makes the code harder to read, as well as making mistakes more likely.  in reality, it would have to be something like if(log.isLogLevelEnabled(LogLevel.A_LOG_LEVEL) log.log(LogLevel.A_LOG_LEVEL, formatString, formatArgs).  Or, the log statement can not take in a log level, making it vulnerable to the bug of not checking whether the statement should get printed.

Comment: @peter: it is the bottleneck.  I am writing a latency-sensitive app and the logging stuff is responsible for about 90% of the garbage generated ...  I wanted to know if there was a way of doing what I was asking for in java.  It's pretty easy in C++ w/ preprocessor and/or templates.  In Lisp, I would make log a macro that would implicitly generate the if(correctLogLevelEnabled).

Comment: @bsdfish perhaps this is a matter of personal taste but I don't find `if (log.isInfoEnabled()) log.info("..");` that bad. log4j API and similar API's do a nice job of making check-if-enabled-then-log as readable and short as possible.

Comment: @bsdfish, whether or not the ifs are "litter" is apparently a matter of personal taste. Since Java has neither preprocessor nor C++ style templates, you just have to decide whether you care more about abstraction violations or performance. IMHO regardless of language, performance optimized code is rarely nice and clean - you must sacrifice something...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should log what you need to log, rather than convert the integers to objects.

Calling logObjs() or log3Obj() to log integers is just a waste of time - you are going to create temporary objects for the boxing/unboxing and they will need to be disposed. Nothing you can do about that.

I suspect that most of the time when you are going to be calling logObjs() you would be passing real objects to the function, in which case the GC cost is almost zero, as you will simply be pass references to those objects into logObjs() and no object creation or disposal is required.

Write several logging functions that take different argument lists appropriate to what you are intending to log at that time. Thats what I do. If I need to log a string and a 32 bit value, I have a logging API with those params, etc. No (or little) un-necessary/temporary object creation.

If you need to log 3 integers write an API that takes 3 integers. If you need to log a weeble object and wobble object and a dont-fall-down object then write an API for that too.
Minimise the box/unobx/GC effects by using appropriate APIs for your logging functions.